# iOS use the delegate pass value not trigger the method

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I was test the delegate pass the value in objective-c.

I know there are other methods can pass string between UIViewControllers like NSNotifyCenter..etc.

Now I want to try to use the delegate pass value .

But I encounter some problems.

I use the navigation and there have two UIViewController(FirstUIViewcontroller and SecondUIViewController).

[image]

Now I want to use manual to change to SecondUIViewController,not use the button drag to the SecondUIViewController at FirstUIViewController.

So I add the code in the **FirstUIViewController.m** button action.

```
 - (IBAction)pushBtnAction:(id)sender {
     SecondViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
 }
```

Then I want to pass the value from the SecondUIViewcontroller when I pop the view controller.

So I add the delegate implement and se the delegate in the **FirstUIViewController.m.**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
     secondVC = (SecondViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
     secondVC.delegate = self;
 }

 -(void) passSecondVC:(SecondViewController *)vc didAddValue:(NSString *)str
 {
     NSLog(@"second str:%@",str);
```

}

In the **SecondUIViewController.h** , I had declare delegate method.

```
 @class SecondViewController;
 @protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

 @optional
 -(void)passSecondVC:(SecondViewController*)vc didAddValue:(NSString*) str;
 @end

 @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

 @property (nonatomic,assign) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

 - (IBAction)passValueDelegatBtnAction:(id)sender;
```

In the **SecondViewController.m** ,

when I click the button will pop self uiviewcontroller and pass the value to FirstUIViewController.

```
 - (IBAction)passValueDelegatBtnAction:(id)sender {
     if( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(passSecondVC:didAddValue:)])
     {
         [self.delegate passSecondVC:self didAddValue:@"this is string from sencond vc"];
     }
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 }
```

(My problems)
**But in this status , I always can't get the value in the delegate method in the FirstUIViewController.**

I had try to other method like below in the FirstViewController.m

```
 - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"segue");
     id vc = segue.destinationViewController;
         if( [vc isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
         {
             SecondViewController *secondVC = vc;
             secondVC.delegate = self;
         }
 }
```

There are same problem.

I can't get the value from the delegate method.

Have anyone know where the problems?

I post my completely code in [here](https://github.com/dickfala/DelegateBugTest.git).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright!

Remove your code from the `viewDidLoad:` method and set the delegate when you push the secondViewController.

```
- (IBAction)pushBtnAction:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [controller setDelegate:self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

**So what was going wrong?**

**Ans**: You create a new object in your viewDidLoad: method and set your firstViewController as delegate to it. Now while pushing you are creating another object of SecondViewController whose delegate is not set.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your code & fixed it.

You don't want this line. so comment it,

```
//    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
//    secondVC = (SecondViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
//    secondVC.delegate = self;
```

Edit this method as below,

```
- (IBAction)pushBtnAction:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Also edit this method as below,

```
- (IBAction)passValueDelegatBtnAction:(id)sender {
//    if( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(passSecondVC:didAddValue:)])
//    {
        [self.delegate passSecondVC:self didAddValue:@"this is string from sencond vc"];
//    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: need't to change passValueDelegatBtnAction

Comment: Yes no need to change passValueDelegateBtnAction. when I was debugging I comment it

Answer (score 0):

you forgot some code in pushBtnAction..

```
- (IBAction)pushBtnAction:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"]; // It's different to VC you init in viewDidLoad 
    controller.delegate = self; // you forgot....
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

prepareForSegue be call when you use **segue** to navigation.